# How to find the true path to the file, even if the file is renamed, moved or deleted

Tags: macos, file

I use this API to open the file, but when the file is renamed, moved or deleted, the API is not useful.

```
NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().openFile(filePath!)
```

In the OSX program, download a file, and then rename it or delete it to the trash can, how to find the real path of this file again, what is related to the API

Comment: Not sure I understand your question, but maybe you can use the *inode number* of the file which is fixed. Try `touch a.txt; ls -i a.txt; mv a.txt b.txt; ls -i b.txt`

Comment: I am developing  a OSX application, in my application, download a file, click the open button can open it, if the user  rename the files or move its position. What can I do when users click the open button again to find the file, and then open it